# How to check if an elements text nodes are all visually empty with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to tell if an element is empty of child elements and visually empty of text. Checking if it has children is the easy part.

```
if ( element.children.length === 0 ) {
  // true
}
```

The hard part is dealing with text nodes that have no visual indicators. For example, an element with `&zwnj;` in it will return a value of 1 when you check it with the following code:

`element.innerText.trim().length`

I want to report an element as empty if after removing all invisible characters, whitespace, and line breaks there is no visible text left. I don't believe `.trim()` has any an additional options so I think that doing a regex replace is the best route?

This is what I'm using right now:

`element.innerText.replace( /(\h|\r|\n|\s|\t|\u0009|\u000a|\u000b|\u000c|\u000d|\u0020|\u0085|\u00a0|\u1680|\u2000|\u2001|\u2002|\u2003|\u2004|\u2005|\u2006|\u2007|\u2008|\u2009|\u200a|\u2028|\u2029|\u202f|\u205f|\u3000|\u180e|\u200b|\u200c|\u200d|\u2060|\ufeff|\u2800)/g, "")`

In addition to `\h|\r|\n|\s|t` I've also pulled characters from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

I do not know if my regex is exhaustive or if I've got some redundancy in here.

Comment: What about a character like 'soft hyphen'. They are only sometimes visible. The '\s' covers many of your characters.

Comment: Trying to parse text from the internet with blacklists is almost a lost cause its only a matter of time until someone finds something you forgot: If you are only targeting websites that use the latin alphabet wouldn't it be simpler to use a whitelist instead? Replace `\h|\r|\n|\s|t|[^\x00-\x7F]`-ish with `[empty string]` and check if anything is left.